# Why Didn't Théoden Let Merry Fight In the Battle At Minas Tirith?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In the Peter Jackson version of *The Return of the King*, Merry offers Théoden his sword and service, which Théoden accepts. Théoden gives Merry the title of "Meriadoc -- Esquire of Rohan."

When the Rohirrim set out to ride to Minas Tirith, Théoden is very firm with Merry, that he is not allowed to ride into battle, and tells Merry that he is a burden that none of the Rohirrim can bear at that time.

**Why didn't Théoden let Merry ride to war?** And yes, I know that Merry was taken into the Battle of the Pellenor Fields by Éowyn, who herself was going to fight on the sly.

Comment: The answers are arriving almost as fast as Legalos's arrows.

Comment: It's knifework down here in the answers sections.

Comment: where was the oath of service in the movie?  i don't remember that, unless it's in the extended/directors cut(s)?

Comment: Theoden knows, and accepts, that riding to war means probable death for himself and most of the Rohirrim. Although he courteously accepted Merry's service, he doesn't think this is Merry's fight as he's not really one of them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you say in your question, it literally is a case of Theoden thinking Merry "is a burden that none of the Rohirrim can bear at that time".  He cannot ride his own horse, and while Merry offers to ride his pony he is knocked back, as the pony would not be able to keep up.

While Tolkien doesn't give an approximate weight of a Hobbit, he gives their average height as three feet six inches in the prologue to the LotR so I'd hazard an estimate of about 30-40kg extra for any horse to be bearing, excluding additional armour for Merry.

That extra weight is for a horse already laden with a full grown and armoured Rohirrim rider, so the concern was about Merry slowing down a given rider on a forced march where they most likely needed (and did need) to be fresh for a charge at the end of it.    It was only the slimmer figure of Eowyn that was able to smuggle Merry without unduly tiring or slowing her steed.

From the Return of the King:

> 'But we ride on horses tall and swift,' said Théoden; 'and great
>   though your heart be, you cannot ride on such beasts.'
>
> 'Then tie me on to the back of one, or let me hang on a stirrup, or something,' said
>   Merry. 'It is a long way to run; but run I shall, if I cannot ride,
>   even if I wear my feet off and arrive weeks too late.'
>
> Théoden smiled. 'Rather than that I would bear you with me on Snowmane,' he said. 'But
>   at the least you shall ride with me to Edoras and look on Meduseld;
>   for that way I shall go. So far Stybba can bear you: the great race will not begin till we reach the plains.'

Also,

> 'This is no journey for such steeds as Stybba, as I have told you ' said Théoden. 'And in
>   such a battle as we think to make on the fields of Gondor what would you do, Master Meriadoc, sword-thain though you be, and greater of heart than of stature?'

Comment: Where did Merry get a pony? The Hobbits, as far as I can recall, ride with others on horseback. :)

Comment: Theoden granted him one called Stybba - "I have had a good hill-pony made ready for you. He will bear you as swift as any horse by the roads that we shall take."

Comment: This didn't appear in any of the movies, did it? I don't recall this from the films.

Comment: Probably not.  A lot of the casual conversations were cut from the films, so it wouldn't surprise me that this was cut as it was only a passing reference.

Comment: I am actually in the process of watching Return of the King, Extended Edition, and as the Rohirrim begin to ride to Gondor's aid Merry is attempting to spur Stybba to move.

Comment: @Chloraphil -- Yes, I saw it too on a re-watch of the extended edition. And I recall that I saw that scene several times before, but didn't realize it was a pony (I thought it was a horse) :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - could have been a miniature horse :)

Comment: +1 and accept -- thank you especially for the canon reference! :)

Comment: The average Hobbit height was three and a half feet but as Merry and Pippin were males belonging to aristocratic families they were probably closer to four feet. After drinking the Ent-draughts they grew to four and a half feet - the tallest Hobbits in the history of the Shire.

Answer (score 13):

Merry wasn’t able to ride a full sized horse by himself, and would have been a burden to both a full grown male warrior and his horse. He would have weighed down the horse, and interferred with the soldier’s ability to fight. Éowyn, being smaller than the average soldier, was able to carry Merry on her horse without slowing it down, as their combined weight was less than that of a fully equipped regular, male warrior.

Comment: It appeared in the movie that Merry was preparing a small-sized horse. :)

Comment: If Bandobras "Bullroarer" Took could ride a horse then Merry and Pippin probably could as well after the Ent-draughts.

Comment: Proving once again that Tolkien isn't real great on practical horsemanship.  I know a number of 5-10 year olds who ride on "horses tall and swift", and - to be perfectly honest - are better riders than I am.

Comment: Major Stackings - Anybody who can ride can ride any horse big enough to bear his weight.  Marry could have ridden the largest horse in the world with the right training.

Comment: @M.A.Golding That maybe so, but the time to receive that training is prior to riding off to war on the horse.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a warrior culture problem. Size and strength are such big advantages in combat that anyone who is smaller or weaker is discounted or even disparaged. Hobbits, being sooooooo much shorter than humans would be thought as children and who, in their right mind would take an eight year old into battle with them?

Comment: I think this is especially the case, as Theoden did not expect to win, or at least, not bring back the majority of his soldiers. He wouldn't take a child into a suicide battle.

Comment: I keep going over this in my mind and I can't quite conclude that Hobbits were so easily dismissed. After all, Frodo, a Hobbit, was charged with carrying the ring to its ultimate destruction, the most dangerous and burdensome task there was. I'd like to think that Hobbits garner respect. OTOH, Éomer did joke to Gamling that he did not doubt Merry's heart, "only the reach of his arm." I should point out that the Rohirrim conscripted very, very young boys for the battle of Helm's Deep at the Hornburg.

Comment: It is very difficult for people to look past their cultural biases - even when they consciously know better. Also, Hobbits aren't knows for being a warrior culture. Quite the opposite in fact.

Comment: @Slytherincess The swelling of ranks with youngsters at Helm's Deep was one of necessity and not something any were proud or eager to do.

Comment: @Josh - I *never* even remotely suggested the Rohirrim were either proud or eager to conscript young boys. I understand they were greatly outnumbered at Helm's Deep. They were also greatly outnumbered at the Battle of Pellinor Fields, though. And Théoden acknowledges that they don't have enough troops to defeat the Uruk'hai and says, "But we will meet them in battle nonetheless."

Comment: @Slytherincess: Wasn't it a point of the whole story that someone as unlikely and looking as weak as a Hobbit changed the fate of the world? Hobbits were small, peaceful creatures, not looking very martial (like the dwarves did), for whom a visit to an inn in Bree was a great adventure. They were called "halflings", and looked like children to the other races. Donald's answer pretty much exactly meets what I thought when reading the question.

Comment: @sbi - I understand this, but all the other characters chose their destinies, even if it included the possibility of death. Of course Théoden had far more character than Denethor.

Comment: @Slytherincess: I'm not sure what you are getting at. Merrin chose his destiny himself, too, after all, no? In the end, Théoden was but one obstacle for him to get passed. The question, as I understood it, was _why_ Théoden became an obstacle, rather than encouraging him. And on that I fully agree with Donald.

Comment: Because if Theoden hadn't blocked him, his pony would have been far behind in the charge, Eowyn would have been killed by the Nazgul King, who would have been free to take Minas Tirith.

Comment: Donald McLean  - "Hobbits, being sooooooo much shorter than humans would be thought as children and who, in their right mind would take an eight year old into battle with them?" During the US Civil War there were a few soldiers and sailors seven or eight years old who went on active campaigns and perhaps into battle, though I am not well informed about the sanity of those who took them close to or even into battle.

Comment: @Slytherincess .. old, I know but the reason Frodo was able to do that is because he was the only one who offered to take it. As Gandalf said later on to return would to be accept defeat and face worse defeat later on. They had no choice. It had to be done.

Answer (score 9):

Théoden accepts Merry's pledge of service, but in good conscience cannot see letting Merry ride into battle against foes twice his size, on a battlefield with horses, oliphants, and god knows what else might be there. Théoden appreciated the gesture and uses the excuse of there not being a warrior able to bear Merry as a burden as a polite way of saying, "stay out of the way."

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Theoden basically didn't want to take Merry, a foreign guest who looked much like a child, into great danger.

Merry certainly could have ridden a full sized horse if he was three or four feet tall and knew how to ride.

Ex cavalry officer Charles King, one of the main inventors of westerns, wrote a novel  *Trumpeter Fred* in which the  title character was small enough to be picked up and put in the saddle,and yet rode the biggest and strongest horse in his troop.

*The Photographic History of the Civil War* in 1911 mentions little scamps of bugle boys who had to be boosted up into the saddle and rode in wild cavalry charges.  A specific example is Jimmie Duggan of the 5th US cavalry who was fourteen years old and only three and a half feet tall in 1861.

https://www.alamy.com/the-photographic-history-of-the-civil-war-thousands-of-scenes-photographed-1861-65-with-text-by-many-special-authorities-i-part-isoldier-life-boys-who-madegood-soldiers-review-of-reviews-co-jimmy-dugan-was-a-bugler-boy-in-the-band-at-carlisle-barracks-the-cavalry-depotin-pennsylvania-as-the-civil-war-opened-one-who-knew-him-writes-he-was-aboutthree-feet-six-high-could-ride-anything-on-four-legs-sound-all-the-calls-and-marchedbehind-the-band-at-guard-mounting-at-the-regulation-twenty-eight-inch-step-at-the-risk-ofsplitting-himself-in-two-jimmy-was-heard-of-later-when-the-serious-image371671085.html

Bugler Joseph Fought, who enlisted in the 5th Cavalry in  1860, was fourteen years old and four feet eight inches tall, much taller than a normal Hobbit but not that much taller than Merry was after drinking an Ent-drink.

A plains Indian boy the size of a Hobbit could have ridden any tamed horse, no matter how large.

Elizabeth Taylor, aged 12, filmed a scene where she fell off a horse in *National Velvet* (1944) and injured her back.

[https://www.vogue.co.uk/arts-and-lifestyle/article/elizabeth-taylor-national-velvet#:~:text=She%20took%20a%20fall%20that%20stayed%20with%20her&text=She%20fell%20and%20broke%20her,%E2%80%94%20and%20very%20real%20%E2%80%94%20fall.](https://www.vogue.co.uk/arts-and-lifestyle/article/elizabeth-taylor-national-velvet#:%7E:text=She%20took%20a%20fall%20that%20stayed%20with%20her&text=She%20fell%20and%20broke%20her,%E2%80%94%20and%20very%20real%20%E2%80%94%20fall.)

Arabian camel races until very recently had small, Hobbit-sized, boys riding racing camels at least as large as most horses.

https://www.tepagency.com/child-camel-jockeys

Many Asian mahouts have ridden and controlled elephants much larger than horses when the mahouts were boys no bigger than hobbits.

Here is a link to a photo from *Elephant Boy* (1937):

https://mubi.com/en/us/films/elephant-boy

Furthermore, if the Rohan riders were like medieval knights they wouldn't have ridden their battle chargers for hundreds of miles to get to the battle.  They would have ridden smaller riding horses for days to reach the battlefield and then mounted their huge chargers to charge into battle.

Tolkien ignores the fact that many mounted war groups brought along several horses for each man, with the riders changing horses from time to time to keep from wearing the horses out.  Many mounted war groups would also have other horses (or mules) to carry supplies.

So in many real life war groups taking one or two more horses to carry a child-sized person to the battle would be no trouble.

So either Tolkien was ignorant of such matters, being an infantry officer in World War I, or else he made Theoden ignore such options because Theoden doesn't want to risk the life of his small new friend in an almost hopeless mission to "ruin and the world's ending".

Comment: You're probably right that he didn't want to take him into a perilous battle but they did ride their horses the whole way. Snowmane for example, the bane of Théoden in the battle. The others had their horses too. They had to have them. Whether or not that's how it was in the real world doesn't matter.